# Effecting a player within a certain radius of coordinates far away from the command block

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I thought it was

```
/effect @a[x=0, y=0, z=0, r=0] 4 10 3
```

and I know for a fact that the chucks are always loaded, but it doesn't work. In minecraft

Answer (score 4):

Spaces are used to separate different arguments in a command. The way that Minecraft will be trying to parse your command currently is:

```
Command:        /effect
Player:         @a[x=0,
Effect:         y=0,
Seconds:        z=0,
Amplifier:      r=0]
HideParticles:  4
?               10
?               3
```

The first error it notices is that `@a[x=0` is an invalid selector/name, so it gives the error message "The entity UUID provided is in an invalid format".

To fix your command, you should remove the spaces after the commas in the selector. Try this command:

```
/effect @a[x=0,y=0,z=0,r=0] 4 10 3
```

Comment: 1.13 syntax: `/effect give @a[z=0,y=0,z=0,distance=..0] mining_fatigue 10 3`